# D3js Line graph doesn't go through all of my points when I use .interpolate('basis')?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

When I try to use  `.interpolate('basis')` an incorrect path is showing in my graph. When it changes to `.interpolate('linear')` it fixes the issue. How can I fix this issue even if I use `.interpolate('basis')`. Here is the plunker `http://plnkr.co/edit/dGjaHXZ186JYzX8IUahw?p=preview` Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that by "incorrect" you mean "doesn't go through all of my points". The `basis` interpolation uses a [b-spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline) which does not have this property -- there's no way to "fix" it, this is simply how it behaves.

You may consider the `cardinal` interpolation instead, which also gives you a smooth curve, but goes through all the points as well. Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AQrPZgoGYC0wKxSbs5Vq?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

Interpolation in D3 represent some mathematical equation to join the different points with a line. Even you can customize the behavior of the interpolations if you feel the default types provided by D3 are not satisfying your needs. These resources can be helpful.

[D3 Documentation Link](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#line_interpolate)

[Example to visualize different interpolations](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4342190)